# Extract number after dot google sheets

Tags: arrays, regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, truncate

I have this Google sheets example. with a column of digits

| Input |
| --- |
| 37.39850912456523, 176.84092312542114 |
| 37.39850912456523, 17.84092312542115 |
| 37.39850912456523, 1.84092312542116 |
| 37.39850912456523, 176.84092312542117 |
| 3.39850912456523, 176.84092312542118 |
| 07.39850912456523, 176.84092312542119 |
| 3.39850912456523, 176.84092312542120 |
| 3.39850912456523, 6.84092312542121 |

I attempted this formula to get the progress table.

```
=ArrayFormula(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A9, "\d{1,3}\.(\d*), \d{1,3}\.(.{5})"))
```

And when trying to get the 5 digits after the dot on the first capture group with  `.{5}` or `\d{5}` i get this error.

```
=ArrayFormula(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A9, "\d{1,3}\.(.{5}), \d{1,3}\.(.{5})"))
```

> Error
> Function REGEXEXTRACT parameter 2 value "\d{1,3}.(.{5}), \d{1,3}.(.{5})" does not match text of Function REGEXEXTRACT parameter 1 value "37.39850912456523, 176.84092312542114".

[image]

| Progress |  |
| --- | --- |
| 39850912456523 | 84092 |
| 39850912456523 | 84092 |
| 39850912456523 | 84092 |
| 39850912456523 | 84092 |
| 39850912456523 | 84092 |
| 39850912456523 | 84092 |
| 39850912456523 | 84092 |
| 39850912456523 | 84092 |

What am I missing to get this result with `REGEXEXTRACT`?

| Desired output |  |
| --- | --- |
| 398509 | 840923 |
| ↓↓↓ | ↓↓↓ |
| ↓↓↓ | ↓↓↓ |
| ↓↓↓ | ↓↓↓ |
| ↓↓↓ | ↓↓↓ |
| ↓↓↓ | ↓↓↓ |
| ↓↓↓ | ↓↓↓ |
| ↓↓↓ | ↓↓↓ |

And eventually, this final result.

| desired results column 1 | desired results column 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 37.398509 | 176.840923 |
| ↓↓↓ | ↓↓↓ |
| ↓↓↓ | ↓↓↓ |
| ↓↓↓ | ↓↓↓ |
| ↓↓↓ | ↓↓↓ |
| 07.398509 | ↓↓↓ |
| ↓↓↓ | ↓↓↓ |
| ↓↓↓ | ↓↓↓ |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

those look like coordinates so better to TRUNC them:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(1/(1/TRUNC(SPLIT(A1:A, ", "), 6))))
```

[image]

if you want it regexed try:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A, "(\d+.\d{6}).*(, \d+.\d{6}).*", "$1$2"), ",")))
```

[image]

---

```
=INDEX(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(A:A, "(\d+.\d{6}).+ (\d+.\d{6})")))
```

[image]

and multiply by 1 if you need values

Answer (score 2):

[image: Formulas]
[image: Result]

As far as I understand RegexExtract returns the matching text if no group is defined, or the first group if one is defined. So, I defined a group for the first five digits and discarded the rest

`=RegexExtract(A1, "\d*\.(\d{1,6})")`

`=RegexExtract(A1, "\d*\.\d*, \d{1,3}\.(\d{1,5})\d*")`

Answer (score 1):

The `split()` function will automatically coerce values to numbers when possible. To get the final desired result you show, use `round()`, like this:

`=arrayformula( trunc( split(A2:A9, ", ", false, true), 6 ) )`

Comment: Hi @-- thaks for the response, 'round()' is not appropriate because value are literal can only be trimmed.

Comment: Use `trunc()`, then. Edited the answer. There will be no difference with the limited sample data you posted. If you need leading zeros be preserved, mention that and show it in your desired results.

Comment: there is an input with leading `0` `07.39850912456523` its easy to miss, and I did't check the result for it, thanks for the note

Comment: Please mention that in the question and show it in your desired results.